# Use if statement to select table to input data based on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database that I am working on. The last part of the work is to send nomination data to different tables based on the zone the user comes from.

There are tree zones (1, 2 and 3) depending on the country you live in. 
What I want to do is enter user nomination into 3 different table based on the zone they belong.

I have tried using the if statement but it's not working for me. The only part that enters a value is when the user is in zone 3 (America) that value is sent to the `america` table. For the other users it does not work. 
Here is my current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    @$email=$_POST['email'];
    $president=$_POST['president'];
    @$vice_president=$_POST['vice_president'];
    @$secretary=$_POST['secretary'];
    @$treasurer1=$_POST['treasurer1'];
    @$treasurer2=$_POST['treasurer2'];
    @$treasurer3=$_POST['treasurer3'];
    @$date= date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    @$voter=$_SESSION['email'];
    $sql = "SELECT zone FROM nickdel_db.students 
            WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('error getting zone');
    $rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result);            

    if($rs[0]==1)
    {                   
        $query = "INSERT INTO nickdel_db.africavote values(Null,'$email','$president','$vice_president','$secretary','$treasurer1','$treasurer2','$treasurer3','$date','$voter')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($query_run)
        {
            echo '<script>alert("You have succefuly nominated executives");</script>';  

            function redirect ($location,$delay=0) {
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='$delay; url=$location' />";
            }
            redirect('https://nci99set.com/homepage.php');
            exit;
        }else{ 
            echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error.</p>'; 
       }
    }elseif($rs[0]==2){                     
                    $query = "INSERT INTO nickdel_db.europevote values(Null,'$email','$president','$vice_president','$secretary','$treasurer1','$treasurer2','$treasurer3','$date','$voter')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($query_run){
                    echo '<script>alert("You have succefuly nominated executives");</script>';  

            function redirect ($location,$delay=0) {
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='$delay; url=$location' />";
            }
            redirect('https://nci99set.com/homepage.php');
            exit;
        }else{ 
            echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error.</p>'; }
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO nickdel_db.americavote values(Null,'$email','$president','$vice_president','$secretary','$treasurer1','$treasurer2','$treasurer3','$date','$voter')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($query_run){
            echo '<script>alert("You have succefuly nominated executives");</script>';  

            function redirect ($location,$delay=0) {
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='$delay; url=$location' />";
            }
            redirect('https://nci99set.com/homepage.php');
            exit;
        }else{ echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error.</p>'; 
        }
    }

}       
else
{
}
```

Comment: Kindly format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: ...and add the `php` tag.

Comment: try using var_dump to check output of query